# Stop playing video in nested UICollectionView in UITableView or Play only on the visible cell in nested structure

Tags: swift, uitableview, video, uicollectionview

I have been struggling with a problem for many days. I am using a nested structure to show multiple photos and videos like Instagram feed. But the problem is when I launch the viewController it starts playing videos and does not stop playing a video on scrolling. How can I play the video only for the visible cell in the nested structure and stop all other video?

Briefly explained my structure here,
UIViewController -> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectioinView -> UICollectionViewCell -> section = 0(For array of Photos) + section = 1(for multiple Videos).

```
extension HomeVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        postsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC
        let objPost = postsArray[indexPath.row]
  
        cell.postImagesArray = []
        cell.postImagesArray = objPost.images ?? [Images].init()
        cell.videos = []
        cell.videos = objPost.videos ?? []
        
        return cell
    }
    

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        guard let tableViewCell = cell as? HomeTVC else { return }
        tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    }
    
}
```

***UICollectionView Delegate Method***

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeCVC
        
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let images = postsArray[collectionView.tag].images?[indexPath.row]
            let imagePath = APIConstants.BasePathImage + (images?.post_merge_image ?? "")
            cell.imgPropertyView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagePath), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
            return cell
        } else {
            let videos = postsArray[collectionView.tag].videos?[indexPath.row]
            cell.videoView.isHidden = false
            let videoUrl = APIConstants.BasePathImage + (videos?.post_video ?? "")
            cell.playVideo(videoUrl)
            return cell
        }

    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
     didEndDisplaying cell: 
        UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? HomeCVC else {return}
        cell.stopVideo()
    }
```

Comment: why is your `didEndDisplaying` method inside `cellForItemAt`?

Comment: can you help with my problem?

Comment: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  didEndDisplaying cell:   UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is defined in `UICollectionViewDelegate` so you should make sure to set the delegate as well as the data source to your tableViewCell like 
`collectionView.dataSource = self` and `collectionView.delegate = self` after doing so the `didEndDisplaying` method in your tableViewCell will be called and your logic should work

Answer (score 1):

So, after being stuck for many days over this and doing numerous efforts I was able to solve it myself. I will post the answer here for you guys.

***Understand the structure***

UITableView > UITableViewCell > UICollectionView > UICollectionViewCell > MultipleSections > VideoLayer > play/pause (For visible cells)

***Solution - Swift 5***

You will assign the tag to the inner UICollectionView using the WillDisplay method of the Outer UITableView and will assign the data in cellForRowat Likewise. So in UICollectionView DataSource/Delegates, you will use these methods.

***CollectionView cellForItemAt Method***

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomeCVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeCVC
            let images = postsArray[collectionView.tag].images?[indexPath.row]
            if indexPath.section == 0 { //if multiple sections for image and videos
                let imagePath = APIConstants.BasePathImage + (images?.post_merge_image ?? "")
                cell.imgPropertyView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imagePath), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
                return cell
            } else {
                let videos = postsArray[collectionView.tag].videos?[indexPath.row]
                cell.videoView.isHidden = false
                let videoUrl = APIConstants.BasePathImage + (videos?.post_video ?? "") //your video Url
                cell.playVideo(videoUrl: videoUrl) // to load the video here and will play in willDisplay
                return cell

            }
//        }


    }
```

***CollectionView didEndDisplaying Method***

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let homeCVC = cell as? HomeCVC {
            homeCVC.stopVideo()
            print("Playing Stopped:")
            
        }
    }
```

***CollectionView willDisplay Methods***

You will do loading the cellForItemAt method of UICollectionView and will just use these methods for playing and stopping the video when the visible cell is in bounds and out of the bouds of the View respectively.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let homeCVC = cell as? HomeCVC {
            
            if indexPath.section == 1 {
                homeCVC.player.play()
                print("Playing Started:")
            }
            
        }
    }
```